# Gedit editor backup of changes

Tags: backup, editor

I had done some changes to a file and i saved it.
After some time I shut down my laptop,
After booting and opening the system , the changes I had done in that file were actually not there.
Please help me to recover the changes done in the file.

Comment: You haven't told us what release/OS you were using, if you were using it as a 'live' system or it was installed, how you shutdown your system (cleanly? or power-off/power-loss & `sync` wasn't performed), you've tagged backup so what backup strategy was used? where the file was located? (local? remote? user directory or where?)  More details may help us to better understand what went wrong...

Answer (score 1):

There is some chance that all these data changes are lost, but here is a little way to find your hidden change if not :

1. Go to your file directory, and look for hidden file

   - on Nautilus, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> or click on [image] -> *Show hidden files*
   - with the terminal, use `ls -a`

   If there is no files revealed, then you had lost your data, and need to retyped then manually
2. Hidden files shown had the same name as the *normal* file with a `~` after the extension (for a file named `file.txt`, his hidden file would be `file.txt~`). You can open it as the standard file, so right click on it -> *Open with Gedit* and save it with a different name (using the terminal, use `gedit file.txt~` to open it, or use `mv file.txt~ newfilename.txt`)

Comment: I believe the `~` files are backup versions before changes are saved. What OP is looking for are work files containing changes that were not saved.